# How to Get Employee Attendance Sum for Whole Month

Tags: mysql

I am working on attendance system and I have table    `tableattendance` with fields
    EMP_ID, 
    DATE_TIME_IN, 
    DATE_TIME_OUT,
ATTANDANCE_STATUS,

When Employee punch on time it treat as "P" and "Y" for late comers. Now I have a query to fetch full month attendance record.

## MySQL Query

```
SELECT  EMP_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-01' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-01',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-02' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-02',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-03' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-03',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-04' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-04',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-05' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-05',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-06' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-06',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-07' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-07',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-08' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-08',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-09' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-09',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-10' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-10',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-11' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-11',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-12' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-12',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-13' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-13',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-14' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-14',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-15' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-15',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-16' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-16',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-17' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-17',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-18' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-18',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-19' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-19',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-20' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-20',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-21' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-21',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-22' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-22',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-23' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-23',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-24' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-24',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-25' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-25',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-26' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-26',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-27' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-27',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-28' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-28',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-29' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-29',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-30' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-30',
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_TIME_IN, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-31' THEN ATTENDANCE_STATUS END) '2014-12-31'
FROM `tblattendance`
GROUP BY EMP_ID;
```

This query work very fine and generate following results.

## Results

```
EMP_ID 2014-12-01  2014-12-02  2014-12-03  2014-12-04  2014-12-05  2014-12-06  2014-12-07  2014-12-08  2014-12-09  2014-12-10  2014-12-11  2014-12-12  2014-12-13  2014-12-14  2014-12-15  2014-12-16  2014-12-17  2014-12-18  2014-12-19  2014-12-20  2014-12-21  2014-12-22  2014-12-23  2014-12-24  2014-12-25  2014-12-26  2014-12-27  2014-12-28  2014-12-29  2014-12-30  2014-12-31  

 1  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           
 2  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           
 3  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           
 4  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           
 5  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           
 6  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           
 7  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           
 8  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           
 9  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           Y           P           P           Y           P           P           Y           P           P           Y           P           
10  P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           P           Y           P           Y           P           P           Y           P           P           Y           P           P           Y           P
```

## Goal

Now my goal is I want to Calculate Total number of presents, and late for each employee at the end of results. Please help anybody.

Comment: It's a shame that you have no presentation layer.

Comment: Why Max? Can an employee have more than one punch in each day?

Comment: can you just provide some sample data for original data and expected output?